# How can i grab the first six characters and then convert them into dates in MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

How can i split the following three varchar columns. and grab certain parts and then convert them into different fields and on one of them convert into datetime format. in SQL 2012

I would like the outcome to be.

```
-   docid, FileName, DealerNo, InvoiceNo, WeekEnding, Doctype, date
```

1, 123InvoiceIn-044632-15021507129,044632,15021507129,**02/15/2015**,123InvoiceIn,

If you notice on # 1. I was able to split the fields but now i also need to convert the first 6 characters of the invoiceno and format them into a date field which should be **02/15/2015** and put that on the Weekending.

```
- docid, FileName, DealerNo, InvoiceNo, WeekEnding, Doctype, date
```

2, 123InvoiceOut-15022238842-150222, 47158, 15022238842, **02/22/2015**, 123InvoiceOut,

If you notice on # 2 the format is a little different. I was able to split the fields but now i also need to convert the first 6 characters of the invoicenoand format them into a date field which should be **02/22/2015** and put that on the Weekending.

```
- docid, FileName, DealerNo, InvoiceNo, WeekEnding, Doctype, date
```

3, 123WrapIn-205251-806-10_04_2013, 205251,806, 123WrapIn, **2013-10-04 00:00.000**

if you notice # three the only thing i need is to convert the date which comes with underscores from the filename column and i need to put that on the date column as datetime

```
CREATE TABLE TEST 
(
docId int,
FileName NVARCHAR(64),
DealerNo NVARCHAR(64),
InvoiceNo NVARCHAR(64),
WeekEnding NVARCHAR(64),
DocType NVARCHAR(64),
Date DATETIME
);

Insert into TEST (docId, FileName, DealerNo, InvoiceNo, WeekEnding, Doctype, date)
VALUES 
(1, '123InvoiceIn-044632-15021507129', '', '', '', '', ''),
(2, '123InvoiceOut-15022238842-150222', '', '', '', '', ''),
(3, '123WrapIn-205251-806-10_04_2010', '', '', '', '', '');
GO
```

I

Comment: Well you can use charindex and substring the get the string out of there, but this looks like a lot of errors (and wrong dates) waiting to happen...

Comment: You can use try_convert at least to protect yourself from cast errors in case you happen to try to convert wrong part of the string

Comment: Do you have any questions regarding my answer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to split the column in SQL using a custom function

```
USE [Test]
GO
/****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[SplitStrings_CTE]    Script Date: 05/02/2013 11:40:24 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitStrings_CTE](@List nvarchar(max), @Delimiter nvarchar(1))
RETURNS @returns TABLE(val nvarchar(max), [level] int, PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED([level]))
AS
BEGIN
;WITH cte AS
 (
  SELECT SUBSTRING(@List, 0, CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @List)) AS val,
         CAST(STUFF (@List + @Delimiter, 1, CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @List), '') AS nvarchar(max)) AS stval,
         1 AS [level]
  UNION ALL
  SELECT SUBSTRING(stval, 0, CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, stval)),
         CAST(STUFF (stval, 1, CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, stval), '') AS nvarchar(max)),
         [level] + 1
  FROM cte
  WHERE stval != ''
  )
  INSERT @returns
  SELECT REPLACE(val, ' ', '') AS val, [level]
  FROM cte
  RETURN
END
```

Then with a SQL trigger that called the function and split and formatted the date using `SUBSTRING`

```
;WITH cte AS
  (  
  SELECT t.docid, t.FILENAME, t.DEALERNO, t.INVOICENO, t.WEEK_ENDING, t.DOCTYPE, 
         NewDOCTYPE = MAX(CASE WHEN o.level = 1 THEN o.val END) OVER(),
         NewDEALERNO = MAX(CASE WHEN o.level = 2 THEN o.val END) OVER(),
         NewWEEK_ENDING = MAX(CASE WHEN o.level = 3 THEN o.val END) OVER(),
         NewINVOICENO = MAX(CASE WHEN o.level = 4 THEN o.val END) OVER()
  FROM dbo.test t CROSS APPLY dbo.SplitStrings_CTE(t.FILENAME, '-') o where t.DOCID=@varDOCID
  )

Update cte
SET DOCTYPE=NewDOCTYPE,
DEALERNO=NewDEALERNO,
WEEK_ENDING=(SELECT
(
    substring(LEFT([NewWEEK_ENDING],6) ,3,2) + '/' + 
       substring(LEFT([NewWEEK_ENDING],6) ,5,2) + '/' + 
       substring(LEFT([NewWEEK_ENDING],6) ,1,2) 

 ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT  *,
        CASE 
            WHEN t.[FileName] LIKE N'%[-]' + REPLICATE('[0-9]', 11) 
                THEN CONVERT(DATE, '20' + LEFT(RIGHT(t.[FileName], 11), 6)) -- For <SQL2008 use [SMALL]DATETIME instead of DATE
            WHEN t.[FileName] LIKE N'%[-]' + REPLICATE('[0-9]', 6)  
                THEN CONVERT(DATE, '20' + RIGHT(t.[FileName], 6))           
            WHEN t.[FileName] LIKE N'%[-][0-9][0-9][_][0-9][0-9][_][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]' 
                THEN CONVERT(DATE, REPLACE(RIGHT(t.[FileName], 10), '_', '/'), 101)
            --ELSE NULL -- Unknow format
        END AS Date
FROM    dbo.TEST t
```

Note: I assume that all dates are >= `2000-01-01`